# Show $1-\frac{3}{4}+\frac{4}{6}-\frac{5}{8}+\frac{6}{10}$.. either converges or diverges.

Tags: proof-verification, alternative-proof

As the title says i have to find out whether the series converges.

I know that every term can be represented by $a_n=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n+1}{2n}=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{n})$. Now we take the partial sum $s_k=\sum(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{2}+\sum{(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}}$ We now take the limit $\lim{s_k}$ and we know the first thing diverges($\sum{(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{2}}$) so the whole thing diverges. Is that correct?

Comment: Have you checked absolute convergence?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that's not correct; you can't split up the terms on a series that might have conditional convergence and expect convergence status to be maintained.

Instead, argue from first principles: for a series $\sum_n a_n$ to be convergent of whatever sort, the terms $a_n$ certainly have to go to zero (why?). Do these?

Comment: Oh wow i completely forgot about that, thanks a bunch. However, why can i not split it up when it is a partial sum? Is this not how we prove the Algebraic Limit Theorem for Series?

Comment: @Sorfosh You can split it up as partial sums.  But then you decided to take the limit of each partial sum separately, which you cannot do.

Comment: The ALT only says that _if_ both series converge, then you can sum them and get an appropriate result. But you can't say a priori that because you can split up into a convergent and divergent series then the original series must diverge.

Comment: @SimpleArt I took the limit of the whole thing and i know that if i take a limit of a divergence + convergent series, i get divergence.

Comment: @Sorfosh Well, that is true, but as it was worded, it was incorrect.  If you follow up with that, then I think you are fine.

Comment: @SimpleArt Ah i see, thanks.